# Glidejs With iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, glidejs

Is it possible to have iframe as an element for glidejs carousel?
When I add iframe as one of the li elements I cannot scroll anymore.

Here is an example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-currying-yvecd?file=/index.html

Comment: Next and Prev work fine in your demo. Not clear what issue is

Comment: I want to be able to scroll to next slide when holding youtube video.

Comment: OK. Problem there is that an iframe creates it's own window completely isolated from parent page window. Events occur in that window, not the parent page window and no way to bubble them to the parent window. In other words, only the youtube pge knows about them

Comment: Is it possible to link the iframe event to parent so glide js can pick it up?

Comment: Not without covering the iframe with another transparent element in the parent page. But that would block access to controls in the iframe

Comment: Or.... shift the iframe down a little bit in the slide so there is a "slide handle" to drag